# Replace case of 2nd column of dataset within awk?

Tags: awk

Im trying command

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}NR>1{tolower(substr($2,2))} {print $0}' emp.txt
```

on below data but not working

```
 - M_ID,M_NAME,DEPT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,Salary 
   M001,Richa,D001,27-Jan-07,27-Feb-07,150000 
   M002,Nitin,D002,16-Feb-07,16-May-07,40000 
   M003,AJIT,D003,8-Mar-07,8-Sep-07,70000 
   M004,SHARVARI,D004,28-Mar-07,28-Mar-08,120000 
   M005,ADITYA,D002,27-Apr-07,27-Jul-07,40000 
   M006,Rohan,D004,12-Apr-07,12-Apr-08,130000 
   M007,Usha,D003,17-Apr-07,17-Oct-07,70000 
   M008,Anjali,D002,2-Apr-07,2-Jul-07,40000 
   M009,Yash,D006,11-Apr-07,11-Jul-07,85000 
   M010,Nalini,D007,15-Apr-07,15-Oct-07,9999
```

Expected output

```
   M_ID,M_NAME,DEPT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,Salary 
   M001,Richa,D001,27-Jan-07,27-Feb-07,150000 
   M002,Nitin,D002,16-Feb-07,16-May-07,40000 
   M003,Ajit,D003,8-Mar-07,8-Sep-07,70000 
   M004,Sharvari,D004,28-Mar-07,28-Mar-08,120000 
   M005,Aditya,D002,27-Apr-07,27-Jul-07,40000 
   M006,Rohan,D004,12-Apr-07,12-Apr-08,130000 
   M007,Usha,D003,17-Apr-07,17-Oct-07,70000 
   M008,Anjali,D002,2-Apr-07,2-Jul-07,40000 
   M009,Yash,D006,11-Apr-07,11-Jul-07,85000 
   M010,Nalini,D007,15-Apr-07,15-Oct-07,9999
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `tolower()` to something, it doesn't operate in place. And in this case, you need to concatenate it with the first character of the field and assign that back to the field.

```
$2 = substr($2, 1, 1) tolower(substr($2, 2));
```

To get comma separators in the output file, you need to set `OFS`. So you need:

```
BEGIN {OFS=FS=","}
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples in GNU `awk` please try following `awk` code. Its using GNU `awk`'s `match` function, where I am using regex `(^[^,]*,.)([^,]*)(.*)` which is creating 3 capturing groups and storing values into an array named `arr`(whose indexes are 1,2,3 and so on depending upon number of capturing groups created). Then if this condition is fine then printing array elements where using `tolower` function to Lower the spellings on 2nd element of arr to get expected output.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
   print
   next
}
match($0,/(^[^,]*,.)([^,]*)(.*)/,arr){
   print arr[1] tolower(arr[2]) arr[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

`mawk`, `gawk`, or `nawk` :

```
awk 'BEGIN { _+=_^=FS=OFS="," } NR<_ || $_ = substr( toupper($(+_)=\
                                tolower($_)), --_,_)  substr($++_,_)'


M_ID,M_name,DEPT_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE,Salary
M001,Richa,D001,27-Jan-07,27-Feb-07,150000
M002,Nitin,D002,16-Feb-07,16-May-07,40000
M003,Ajit,D003,8-Mar-07,8-Sep-07,70000
M004,Sharvari,D004,28-Mar-07,28-Mar-08,120000
M005,Aditya,D002,27-Apr-07,27-Jul-07,40000
M006,Rohan,D004,12-Apr-07,12-Apr-08,130000
M007,Usha,D003,17-Apr-07,17-Oct-07,70000
M008,Anjali,D002,2-Apr-07,2-Jul-07,40000
M009,Yash,D006,11-Apr-07,11-Jul-07,85000
M010,Nalini,D007,15-Apr-07,15-Oct-07,9999
```

Comment: which language is this?

Comment: @Faisal : `awk`